# Typescript. How to split index.d.ts

Tags: typescript

I want to split my index.d.ts to separate files. But when i use 'import' all types is undefined.

I have following structure in my root:

```
types
   |--custom
      |--index.d.ts
      |--task.d.ts
```

In tsconfig.json : `"typeRoots": "types"`

index.d.ts:

```
import { Task } from ‘./task’;
type Project = {
    title: string;
    tasks?: Task[];
};
```

task.d.ts:

```
export type Task = {
    title: string;
};
```

What i doing wrong?

Comment: Creating an index.d.ts file in your types root that references each of your custom d.ts files might work?   e.g.  /// <reference path="custom/index.d.ts" /> etc

Comment: Tnx! This work.
I add in index.d.ts  '/// <reference path="task.d.ts" />'.

Comment: @83N But i don't understand how work 'import' for example here:

[https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/selenium-webdriver](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Check out the [npm Typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings)  package and the [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html)